# How to map my new domain from domain.com to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently bought a domain from *Domain.com*, how can I map the domain to my application hosted on AWS elastic beanstalk. I have tried Route53, Requesting a certificate, but halfway I simply not getting it. I tried to transfer, but *domain.com* is preventing me from making the transfer. Please how can I map the domain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a CNAME for your domain at domain.com and in the value put your EB application URL.

Comment: That won't even save

Comment: Don’t put the https

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. And I was able to figure the AWS process out.

Comment: Great! Good luck!